# Why is my string interpolation not working

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I used backticks yet the string interpolation is not working, what's even weirder is that it is sometimes working in other parts of the code.

It's not working here

```
let files = getFiles(`./commands/${category}`, ".js")
```

But it is working here

```
if (reload)
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${category}/${f}`)]
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
let files = getFiles(`./commands/${category}`, ".js")
                                           ^

ReferenceError: category is not defined
```

Comment: How have you concluded that the string interpolation is the issue and not, say, your `getFiles()` function? Have you tried assigning ` ./commands/${category} ` to a variable and logging it?

Comment: Define "not working."

Comment: I updated the question to show my error

Answer (score 1):

The error you got (`ReferenceError: category is not defined`), shows that the variable `category` is not defined in the scope of that line. Make sure that if you're using `let`, the variable isn't defined within an inner-block, such as a loop for a if-statement. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let